# how to do string enums and such in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have filenames and such that are NSStrings.  I have to keep typing them in and I may mistype and cause an error.  How does the experienced objective C programmer handle this so they only type it in once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the header:

```
extern NSString * const kMyFile;
```

in the implementation file

```
NSString * const kMyFile = @"FileName.txt";
```

You get code completion on it this way.

Or, if it is only being used in one class and doesn't need to be exposed in the header you could just do

```
static NSString * const kMyFile = @"FileName.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //assign names here
    //create variable names in the header-->   NSArray *filename;

    filename = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"File1", @"File2", nil];

    //[filename objectAtIndex: i]  --> NSString 
}
```